# Creating .exe file in Qt 4.10.2

Tags: c++, qt, dll, exe

My degubber (MinGW) create .exe file. But .exe file didnt work. I searched and I added some .dll by using windeployqt.exe. Exe files starts to run but when I carried it to another computer(not having qt) or changed the the C:/Qt folder name to another name, Exe didnt start.

I used Dependency Walker program to find missing .dll but program showed me a lot of missing .dll. How can I add all dll to my exe.

I am using community version. Is there a reason? or I am doing another mistake.
For missing dll: https://hizliresim.com/EOdL5z

Comment: When you install your program on a computer you need to also install all libraries that it uses. You can't just copy the .exe on its own. Look into creating a proper .MSI installer for your application that will install *all* required files.

Comment: It takes long time. Thank you for explanation. I will investigate .MSI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this website "https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Applicstacation_on_Windows" step by step and I changed inside the qt.conf file as

```
[Paths]
Plugins = plugins
Prefix = ./
```

and then my .exe run Thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

You can simply copy the missing DLLs from the Qt install directory (on Windows is usually C:/Qt/4.10.2/...). On other PCs the procedure is the same, copy all the dependencies in the `.exe` folder (DLLs, plugins, translations...); also, side node, when deploying applications you should build the software in release mode!

With the WinDeploy tool, you can prepare a package to be shipped combining the output with QtInstallerFramework or InnoSetup to create an installer!

Reference: [Windows Deploy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html), [Qt Installer Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html), [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I don't understand why qt performs this procedure internally. I think copying dll takes a time. My program is simple. What if I make a big program? In visual studio if there is no plugin I can carry exe (e.g form applicaiton). Anyway, I will try what you say as soon as possible time.

Comment: @GUI_27 With programs built using the visual studio compiler (with or without Qt) you also have to install the Visual Studio redistributable runtime along with your program. Just copying the executable is not enough in the general case.

Comment: Actually my pc have redistributale x64 2005, 2008, 2010, 2015. But i cant find API-MS-WIN-CORE dll files in my pc(both in qt and in windows file). I am doing sfc/scannow in cmd maybe it can work but i dont think. Where can I find API-MS-WIN-CORE dlls? Should I download all of them from some dll websites?